# Rendering date into grid as relative time ("5 seconds ago") and updating it in real time (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF, XAML and C# to produce a grid which listens to a source of models which have a  date field that I want to display relatively. Currently it is displayed with `.ToString()`, but my actual question is that how would I implement the relative timing (or the active formatting of it) possible in every second. Is there some preferred way to force re-rendering of the UI, because the data does stay the same all the time (only one column needs to be redrawn once a second and the corresponding formatting method called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding to a view model, then you can just raise a property change every second.

```
   public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
       private void OnTimerTick()
       {
           OnPropertyChanged("Date");
       }

       public string Date
       {
           get{ return DateTime.Now().AddSeconds(-5).ToString();
       }
   }
```

Where ViewModelBase implements *INotifyPropertyChanged* and you are using a DispatcherTimer to raise the timer tick event.

Comment: Hmm, currently it's bound to an observable collection, and the collection is a property of the viewmodel. Should I change my approach?

Comment: So each individual item in the collection has a time property?  If so you could iterate over the collection raising OnPropertyChange for each item.